# Not able to configure JMS 2.0, ActiveMQ 5.x, and Karaf

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, apache-karaf

I have been trying to setup pax-jms with ActiveMQ in Apache karaf. Following are the respective versions, that I have installed:

```
activemq-osgi: 5.15.3
OPS4J Pax JMS * : 1.0.3
Karaf: 4.2.0
JMS API: 2.0.1
```

These are the features that I had installed:

```
> feature:repo-add mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jms/pax-jms-features/1.0.3/xml/features 
> feature:install pax-jms-activemq pax-jms-config
```

I can see that my configurations are being picked up properly. Thus, executing the command `jms:connectionfactories` shows the connection that I had configured.

Note: I followed https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/spaces/PAXJMS/pages/331350050/Configuration, believing that the steps would have been similar for ActiveMQ as well.

My configuration looks as follows:

```
jms.url=tcp://localhost:61616
jms.username=system
jms.password=manager
type=activemq
osgi.jndi.service.name=jms/demo.consumer
```

For the time being, I just wanted to test whether or not I can query the ActiveMQ broker from Karaf. Thus, I tried `jms:info jms/demo.consumer`. But, I am consistently getting the following error message:

`Error executing command: JMS 2.0 is not supported by ActiveMQ`

I have tried changing the versions, tried on fresh karaf instances as well. But, I had no luck so far. Am I missing some fundamental steps here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pax-jms-activemq module support ActiveMQ 5.x. The command line tools may not work b/c it calls ConnectionFactory.createContext() instead of .createConnection().  JMS v2.0 has a couple features that ActiveMQ 5.x does not support-- shared durable subscriptions, basically.

As long as the code that gets the ConnectionFactory calls .createConnection() instead of .createContext() it'll work just fine with the JMS API 2.0 jars. Java code, camel-activemq, camel-jms, etc will all work fine.

Comment: well, my scenario was to use pax-jms to configure the broker(ActiveMQ), and use it alongside camel. I looked at the source of pax-jms-activemq as well. Your answer clarified these things. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is accurate. ActiveMQ 5.x doesn't support JMS 2.0. This isn't a configuration issue. It's simply not implemented.  If you want JMS 2.0 support from an ActiveMQ broker then you should use [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/). For what it's worth, the [documentation you referenced](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/spaces/PAXJMS/pages/331350050/Configuration) is using ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: ok. thank you very much. I will try this out with Artemis then.